# Convert image base64 to base30

Tags: javascript, html, base64, signature

I want save signature in database but image base64 string is very long (about 15 000 characters) any simple solution for convert base64 to base30?

Here is my example, I'm try add `signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jSignature;base30");` but not working.

```
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad"),
    clearButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=clear]"),
    saveButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=save]"),
    canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas"),
    signaturePad;

function resizeCanvas() {
    var ratio =  Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
    canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();
alert(canvas);
signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

//Here get base64 string

saveButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

        document.getElementById("signatureDiv").value = signaturePad.toDataURL();
        saveToDB(signaturePad.toDataURL);
    }
});
```

Comment: A base30 string is going to be even longer..

Comment: base30 representations will be longer than base64?

Comment: In this example http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/demo/ , after draw signature and chose base30 string is shortly then base64

Comment: @paris0000. that looks like a custom library for svgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what are you trying to do is **not passable**

check out this [link](https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad/blob/gh-pages/documentation.md#client-side) on line *toDataURL() method of <\canvas>* that mean that the `toDataUrl`is the canvas method and the first param of the `toDataUrl` get in witch format to convert to [base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) bitmap.